# ADF Data Bricks Connection Error with ODBC linked service

Tags: odbc, azure-data-factory, databricks

I have a Data Factory using an ODBC data source linked service with the connection string being fed from key vault with the format (the token right now I am using is my personal token):

```
Driver=Simba Spark ODBC Driver;Host=adb-xxxxxxxx687.7.azuredatabricks.net;Port=443;HTTPPath=/sql/1.0/warehouses/b5fcc515eaxxxx;ThriftTransport=2;SSL=1;AuthMech=3;UID=token;PWD=xxxx
```

Now I have a working ADF pipeline using this ODBC connection that reads from this Data Bricks instance and writes into our Azure SQL DB.  Now my client has asked me to do the opposite and write data into a Data Bricks SQL table.  When I attempt a table copy activity in ADF using the Databricks ODBC connection as the sink I get the following error even though when I test the linked service the connection is successful:

```
"Message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDbConnectionString,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The connection string provided is invalid.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.ArgumentException,Message=Keyword not supported: 'driver'.,Source=System.Data
```

I have checked my permissions on the Databricks instance and I know I have permissions to create tables, but I'm confused as to why I would need a different connection string format to write to Databricks.  Does anyone know what I need to change?

Comment: Could you please provide the complete error message?